# Can't change m2m relation on model save()

Tags: django, django-orm

I have custom user model with `is_instructor` field and would like to add user to **Instructors** group if this value is `True`. I tried to do it by overriding save() method and using signal, but neither of them worked.

**This does not work:**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    is_instructor = models.BooleanField(_('instructor'), default=False)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        super(CustomUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        ins_group = Group.objects.get(name='Instructors')
        if self.is_instructor:
            self.groups.add(ins_group)    # No effect
        else:
            self.groups.remove(ins_group) # No effect
```

Same using signal (**does not work**):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def update_groups(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    ins_group = Group.objects.get(name='Instructors')
    if instance.is_instructor:
        instance.groups.add(ins_group)    # No effect
    else:
        instance.groups.remove(ins_group) # No effect
```

**Though it works fine in a view:**

```
def update_user(request, pk, template='userprofile/customuser_form.html'):
    ...
    profile = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(), id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            u = form.save(commit=False)
            ins = Group.objects.get(name='Instructors')
            if u.is_instructor:
                u.groups.add(ins)    # Works
            else:
                u.groups.remove(ins) # Works
            u.save()
            redirect('userprofile:detail', u.pk)
    ...
```

But I need to do it in models to update groups when saving user in admin as well. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Is the `groups` field by any change included in the `ModelForm`?

Comment: No, it is not included in form.

Comment: Show us the definition of the model form you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The save() doesn't work for new instances because you try to modify relations before calling super.

The signal may simply not be loaded. Which module did you put it into (`models.py` hopefully?). Check that `update_groups` is even called when you expect it to.

As a side-note: when working with signals, remember to respect the `raw` keyword argument.

Comment: It doesn't matter for `save()`, in fact I do call super (in place of ellipsis) before updating groups, and then save the model instance again. I updated the code in question. As for signal, yes, the code lives in **models.py** and the signal is issued when expected, I checked that with **pdb** on dev server. **raw argument** -- what do you mean? Could you please provide a link to docs?

Comment: Sure, `raw` docs are found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save and it says:

raw
    A boolean; True if the model is saved exactly as presented (i.e. when loading a fixture). One should not query/modify other records in the database as the database might not be in a consistent state yet.

I am sorry I missed the first super save. Why do you call it twice then (not the particular problem you are experiencing, but still confuses me)?

Comment: Oops, you are right, the first `save()` would be enough, thanks for pointing out. Updated the code. And thank you for helping!